# C# Adding '[' ']' to variable for TableName Usage

Tags: c#, string, ssis

Im working inside a SSIS package. I have some C# script for placing Table Names into an Object Variable (Access tables). The code connects to an Access DB and loops for tables obteining their names into the variable.

the allocation goes as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_9b2714c55db14556be74ca92f345c4e3.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            Variables varCollection = null;
            DataTable schemaTables = null;
            ArrayList tableNames = new ArrayList();

            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::AccessTables");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Dts.Connections["TE030698.Bases"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                string[] restrictions = new string[4];
                restrictions[3] = "Table";
                connection.Open();
                schemaTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTables.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTables.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.ColumnName.ToUpper() == "TABLE_NAME")
                    {
                        tableNames.Add(row[column].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            varCollection["User::AccessTables"].Value = tableNames;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Problem is some tables start with numbers or contain spaces. So I need the names to be held in []. 2012 is a table but I need it to be [2012]. How could I change the C# code to do that?

Im pretty new to C# so any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Ehm, you write "["+name+"]"? I'm not sure what the problem is. The only problem I can see is with the namespace.

Comment: What is 2012? I don't see it in the above code?

Comment: 2012 is an existing table name inside the Access DB.

Comment: Taking a quick stab: tableNames.Add("[" + row[column].ToString() + "]");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change

```
tableNames.Add(row[column].ToString());
```

to

```
tableNames.Add(string.Format("[{0}]", row[column].ToString()));
```

More information on `string.Format`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

The alternative is to simply concatenate:

```
tableNames.Add("[" + row[column].ToString() + "]");
```

Concatenation is discouraged, however, if your formatting ever becomes remotely complex.

Comment: @Jay, IMO, in this case concatenation is preferred as compare to String.Format

Comment: @Habib.OSU Hm. Because you can leave out the `.ToString()` from row[column] when doing a `Format`, I'd prefer the `Format`.

Answer (score 1):

If the table name is `"2010"` you just wrap it in square brackets, so `"[" + "2012" + "]"`.

if you have the '2012' in a variable you could do something like

```
string strTableName = "2012";
strTableName = String.Format("[{0}]", strTableName);
```

I hope this helps.